# Question about calculating Lie bracket given a three dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose we have $\frak{g}\in\mathbb{R^3}$ spanned by $X, Y, Z$ such that $[X,Y]=Y, [X,Z]=Y+Z$. What is $[Y, Z]$?

I tried to expand the bracket, $[X, Y]=XY-YX=Y, [Y, X]=YX-XY$, but don't see how to proceed otherwise.

Comment: Usually, when one does not specify the bracket of a pair of elements in a basis of a Lie algebra, what it means is that the bracket is zero.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I have got the same calculations as Mark but don't know how to conclude at the end. Can you comment?

Comment: You can't conclude anything: the two brackets you wrote do not determine the third one.

Comment: As I said, the usual convention in presenting a Lie algebra is to write down only the nonzero brackets.

Comment: (actually, they do determine it (the equation Mark got says that [y,z] is an eigenvector for [x,-] of eigenvalue 2, and the relations you wrote tell you that [x,-] has eigenvalues 1 and 0: this implies that [y,z]=0) but it is most surely not the intention of the author that you do this)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with Lie brackets, so I only have  a partial answer via the properties from their wikipedia page.  Hopefully someone else can do the final step.

Recall the *Jacobi Identity* $$[X,[Y,Z]]+[Z,[X,Y]]+[Y,[Z,X]]=0$$
As $[X,Y]=Y$, this gives us that
$$[X,[Y,Z]]+[Z,Y]+[Y,[Z,X]]=0$$
Also, recall that the Lie bracket is antisymmetric, so $[X,Y]=-[Y,X]$.  We can further reduce this to
$$[X,[Y,Z]]-[Y,Z]+[Y,-[X,Z]]=[X,[Y,Z]]-[Y,Z]+[Y,-Y-Z]=0$$
Finally, the Lie bracket is bilinear, so we can expand the last bracket, getting:
$$[X,[Y,Z]]-[Y,Z]-[Y,Y]-[Y,Z]=0$$

$[\cdot,\cdot]$ being antisymmetric implies that $[Y,Y]=0$, so we have that $$[X,[Y,Z]]-2[Y,Z]=0$$
Hopefully, from here the answer is much more achievable.